# How do i store an array in localstorage and then get the contents and then add them to a select object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is the code i am using to get the array and then add them to the select object.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var theArray = localStorage.getItem("array")
JSON.parse(theArray)
if (theArray != null){
  for (var i=0; i > theArray.length; i++){
    select.add(theArray[i])
  }
}
```

Here is the code i am using to set the localStorage values.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = visText;
      option.value = actVal;
      select.add(option)
      theArray[theArray.length+1] = option;
localStorage.setItem("array",JSON.stringify(theArray))
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: looks like the second section is in a loop? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: what is the code you need?

Comment: all of the relevant code? the entire loop..wherever theArray is defined etc

Comment: theArray is defined in the second line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to assign the parsed Json to a variable:

```js
let select = document.getElementById('select')
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('array'))

for(let entry of data) {
  select.add(new Option(entry))
}
```

Not 100% sure if it works but should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the session and local storage with dot notation. The snippet below shows this. However, the snippets here are sandboxed, and cannot be written to. So, to demonstrate how to populate a select element from an array, I used a `try..catch` block so when it errored out, it would at least populate the select options with the original `array` variable.

```js
const array = new Array(10).fill(0).map((elm, idx) => (elm = idx, elm));
let arrayFromStorage;

try {
  window.localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(array);
  arrayFromStorage = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.myArray);
} catch (error) {
  console.warn(error.message)
  arrayFromStorage = array;
}

arrayFromStorage.forEach(elm => {
  const opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = elm;
  opt.innerText = `option ${elm}`;
  document.querySelector('select').append(opt);
})
```

```html
<select></select>
```

If you copy/paste this into a browser console, you can see that it can be set and called using dot notation

```js
const array = new Array(10).fill(0).map((elm, idx) => (elm = idx, elm));
let arrayFromStorage;
window.localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(array);
arrayFromStorage = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.myArray);
```